# How does it know which method to call?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This is a follow-on from a previous question, in the implementation, I have two methods, one which gets called when a particular service is found and the other when it vanishes. This might be a dumb question, but apart from the NSLog lines they are identical, what dictates which gets called?

```
// INTERFACE
@interface ITunesFinder : NSObject <NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate>
@end
```

.

```
// IMPLEMENT
@implementation ITunesFinder

// ------------------------------------------------------------------- **
-(void) netServiceBrowser: (NSNetServiceBrowser *) browser
           didFindService: (NSNetService *) service
               moreComing: (BOOL) moreComing {
    [service resolveWithTimeout:10];
    NSLog(@"Service Found: %@", [service name]);
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------- **
-(void) netServiceBrowser: (NSNetServiceBrowser *) browser
         didRemoveService: (NSNetService *) service
               moreComing: (BOOL) moreComing {
    [service resolveWithTimeout:10];
    NSLog(@"Service Lost!: %@", [service name]);
}
@end
```

gary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not identical. The one has a parameter: **didFindService** and the other has a parameter **didRemoveService**.

Comment: it's not a parameter, it's part of the method name.

Comment: Ah indeed they do, many thanks. I think I need to take a break, I have  been looking at that for 30mins and scratching my head.

Comment: So basically what we have is two different method names, accessed via the browser delegate ITunesFinder.

Comment: @Dave - have a look at Figure 2 on this page: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/

Comment: @fuzzygoat - yes, correct. The methods have different signatures based on the fact that their parameter names differ.

Comment: @Dave - I must apologize - they are not parameter names but "method definition keywords".

Comment: @rein - np. selectors in objc are strange and take some getting used to. =)

Comment: Thanks for the primer link, I have not seen that before. I will print it and have a read right now.